# Async/Await Email Validation

Tags: validation, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to write a function that checks an email entered into a form input using Async/Await. It looks something like this:

```
//Check email entered
if($('email')){
    $('email').observe('blur', function() {

        //Validate email
        (async () => {
            await resetMessages('email');
            checkEmptyField('email');
            checkEmailExists(); //Checks if email already exists.
            checkEmailDomain(); //Checks for a valid domain.
        })()

    });
}
```

I am completely new to Async/Await and frankly don't know what I am doing, still trying to wrap my head around it.

Obviously, I want to check each function and only pass on to the next function if the previous test passes. Conversely, if the field is empty for example, message the user and don't move to the next function.

Here is an example of the checkEmailExists() function:

```
function checkEmailExists() {

    const email = $F('email');

    if(email!=''){
        const url = '/global/validate/?action=check-email-exists&e=' + email;
        let result;

        fetch(url)
        .then(async function(data){
            result = await data.text();
            if(result == 'OK'){
                setMessage('message', defaultMessage, 'classInfo');
                $('email').addClassName('ok-field');
            }
            if(result == 'EXISTS'){
                setMessage('message', 'Email address is already registered., 'classBad');
                $('email').addClassName('bad-field');
            }
            if(result == 'INVALID'){
                setMessage('message', 'Email address is invalid.', 'classBad');
                $('email').addClassName('bad-field');
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to do this, can someone help me out with coding this properly.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You check email function should return a promise for it to be awiatable.

So, return fetch call.

Comment: Thank you for your response. A quick example of this would be helpful.